# Unable to fetch odata request parameter and values

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I have a webapi 2 project. I am making below calls to fetch parameter and values specified but RouteData is empty.

```
 var routeData = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
 var id = routeData.Values["contextId"] as string;
```

This is the url : `http://localhost:29016/api/v1/Contexts(1)/Applications`

and routing is setup like this,

```
        // OData routing.
    _configuration.MapODataServiceRoute(
            "ODataRoute",
            "api/v1/Contexts({contextId})",
            GetModel(_configuration));
```

I need contextId parameter value before Controller action is called. I have verified that `HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext` refers to the correct request.